# Customer new address attribue not showing up in address book

Tags: attributes, frontend, customer-address

I have created a customer address attribute but it is not showing up in front end ( Address Book ) , but it is showing up in admin panel.
I have cleared `cache` and `reindexed` the indexes also

Refer the images , I am I doing something wrong here or it is not possible in magento ?[image: Setting Of New address attribute]

[image: Not Displaying in Front End Address Book]

Answer (score 1):

Here http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/29/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address/ You have how to add new address field. Edit `Address format` settings it should help in this case, but in some places you should edit template files.

Comment: Oh It seems it need to be implement with codes, isnt it possible with settings itself ? Anyways thanks

Comment: No but there you have easy step by step description how to make it :)

Comment: Yup I can see that :)